# How Can I write Gherkin script writing as I am a beginner and I dont know where to start

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

Can someone save my life? How can I create two simple test cases written in the descriptive language Gherkin (maximum 10 lines)? Based on the popular messenger app WhatsApp (example: “send message button” functionality) or the [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) (example: “search” functionality).

I am not quite familiar with Cucumber Gherkin Script writing. I am just getting started and I dont know where to start

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of [tutorial videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0Q5orC5jSQ) online, and the [documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/) is also very informative, so you may start there. 
 Anyway, here's an example:

```
Feature: Whatsapp

  Scenario: Succesful Log in
    Given a user opens Whatsapp on their device
    When the user enters valid credentials to login
    Then the the log in is successful 

  Scenario: Unsuccesful Log in
    Given a user opens Whatsapp on their device
    When the user enters invalid credentials to login
    Then the log in is unsuccessful
```